NextJs open and close side drawer with app router
I have created a NextJs app router to achieve the routes as follows:

/chat/conversation_id -> /chat/new or /chat = Open in full main layout
/chat/conversation_id/history -> /chat/new/history or /chat/id/history = Open in the - side drawer along with chat
/chat/conversation_id/files -> /chat/new/files or /chat/id/files = Open in the side drawer along with chat
/chat/conversation_id/<etc> = Open such routes in the side drawer along with chat
/settings = Open in full main layout

In the app router added the chat section as a slot and history and files as routable through the children in layout. With this when navigated to /chat/conversation_id/history the side drawer is opening. On soft navigating back to /chat/conversation_id the side drawer still shows the content of history. but on the hard navigation history drawer closes.




The layout file code: chat/[conversationId]/layout.tsx
export default function ChatLayout({
  children,
  chatbot
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
  chatbot: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  // console.log("children", children)
  return (
    <div className="flex h-full flex-row">
      {children}
      <div className="flex-1">{chatbot}</div>
    </div>
  )
}


Even have tried to hide children as chat/[conversationId]/default.tsx return null
Questions:

Can something like this be achievable in an app router, If achievable please share samples or do I have to do a side drawer in the chat page and toggle the side drawer with query params?
Can new chat be routed to /chat instead of /chat/new. This I was doing because I can`t have empty before the history path /chat/<empty>/history?
At the start of the chat I am trying to replace the path with /chat/id but if did so the page redirects or renders. Can we do a soft change of the URL without redirecting or re-rendering?


I was able to get this working.
Answers:

I have updated the chat/[conversationId]/layout.tsx to check the pathname if history or files are not in the path name hiding the children.
Code:

'use client'

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

export default function ChatLayout({
  children,
  chatbot
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
  chatbot: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  const pathname = usePathname()

  const showDrawer = pathname.includes('history') || pathname.includes('files')
  return (
    <div className="flex h-full flex-row">
      {showDrawer && <div>{children}</div>}
      <div className="flex-1">{chatbot}</div>
    </div>
  )
}


This can be done by having the same routes under /chat as well as /chat/[conversationId]. But I am skipping this, I do conditional rendering with /chat/new and /chat/id
I am using browser native API window.history.pushState to do shallow routing. NextJS doc reference

